# how to calculate time taken to execute an instruction in keil c

Tags: c, keil

I am using a for loop which will increment from 0 to 30000 to make some delay between led ON /OFF states.  How to find the exact delay taken by the for loop. The code is used for Micro Controller AT89C51ED2 with 11.0592 MHZ oscillator frequency.  I have tried with delay functions preferred by some programmers too. But I couldn't see that LED was blinking.

Comment: Is your code executing at all?  Is the LED on, off or at 'half bright'?  What happens when you scope the LED?  Does your debugger show that the loop is being executed?  YOU have to debug this - we can't help at all with what you have told us, or with possibly hardware problems at all :(

Comment: Yes it is successfully compiled and .hex file also created.  I have chosen P1.0 for LED blinking. In debug mode i am able to see that the P1.0 is blinking by using Peripherals->I/O Ports -> Port 1.  But in hardware it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Either you go and you use `Dissassembly` window to see instructions for your loop and calculate number of cycles for each instruction for your loop of `3000` times or...

..go to debug, open `Registers` window and there is `States` parameter which tells you how many cycles were required for specific step in your code.

When debugging, move to beginning of loop, save states and then go after loop and check again. Subtract values and you have number of states.